Necessary condition for unique point of minimum
My objective the following:

Consider a function of two variables $f_{\xi}(x,y):\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which depends on a parameter $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^+$, where
$f_{\xi}(x,y)$ is a continuous function and $f_{\xi}(x,y)\geq0$ $\forall$ $((x,y),\xi)$.
Find a necessary condition for the function to have exactly one unique point of minimum (which is also the global minimum).

A sufficient condition would be for the function to be strictly convex in its domain, but, again, my focus here is on finding a necessary condition.
A simple way would be to derive the function and find two sets of points $((x_1, y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ such that they are two different points of minimum. However, the function might be extremely difficult to derive.

Could you please clarify what is meant by "one point of minimum"? Do you mean there is just one global minimum, or do you mean that also there is only one local minimum?
